# Can a magento shopping cart website be migrated into a Yii framework instead?

Tags: magento, zend-framework, yii, frameworks, migration

I have a question, can a magento store shopping cart website based on zend framework be migrated into a new Yii framework website instead of using zend?
Thanks.

Comment: Does my answer respond to your question? If yes, please accept it and mark as valid. Others can find your question, as well as my answer, useful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think so. Magento is build on ZF, and migrate to YII is not an easy job (and furthermore, Magento developers should make this big-effort, not others).

Anyway, I guess you would ask a different thing: Can Magento be **installed** on Yii framework in order to have **both environments work**?
The answer is YES.

I did it in this way:

1. Starting from your Yii installation, add a folder called shop (it's just an example, of course you can choose any name you like):

   ```
   mywebsite
      |-css
      |-images
      |-protected
      |-shop   (<- add it at same level of protected folder)
      |-tests
      |-theme
   ```
2. Install Magento source in such folder and now change your Yii index.php file in this way:

   ```
   <?php

   function recursive_str_replace($replacethis,$withthis,$inthis)  {
       $inthis = str_replace($replacethis, $withthis, $inthis);
       if (stristr($inthis, $replacethis) !== FALSE)
           return recursive_str_replace($replacethis, $withthis, $inthis);
       return $inthis;
   }

   $request_uri = strtolower(recursive_str_replace('//', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));

   //if we don't need to load Magento, then load Yii framework!
   //otherwise let Magento autoloader do its job 
   if (strpos($request_uri, '/shop/') === false){
       //run your Yii app as usual
       // change the following paths if necessary
       $yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../framework/yii.php';
       $config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';

       // remove the following line when in production mode
       defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);

       require_once($yii);
       Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
   }
   ```
3. Last step: tell Magento the new `base_url` value, either via Admin Panel or `core_config_data` table.

That's all

Comment: Thanks for the info!
Could I eventually do the same way if I wanted to have magento run on C++ framework or the only possible way is to use the following for fast performance and cpu resources.
As I hate zendframework I want to switch eather to java or net , c++ platform.
I know that facebook translates php code into c++ so my question is what would you advise me for a successfull project migration from the below tools,
regards, 

Facebook tools:

http://hhvm.com/

Or Microsoft tool:

http://phalanger.codeplex.com/